# Spring boot: Should I close body stream http client

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, stream

I've coded this code snippet:

```
ReferenceComposition reference = this.restTemplate.execute(uriToCall, HttpMethod.GET, null, clientHttpResponse ->
        this.extractReferenceFromResponse(
            this.getReferenceHeader(clientHttpResponse),
            this.getReferenceStream(clientHttpResponse.getBody())
        )
    );
```

Should I close `InputStream` returned by `clientHttpResponse.getBody()` after having called `this.extractReferenceFromResponse(..)`? `getReferenceStream` only use the `InputStream` for creating a temp file.

`getReferenceStream` is:

```
/**
 * Creates a temporarily file.
 * @param referenceStream response stream
 * @return Temp created file
 */
private InputStream getReferenceStream(InputStream referenceStream) {
    try {
        File tmpReferenceFile = File.createTempFile("reference", "tmp");
        OutputStream contentOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpReferenceFile);
        StreamUtils.copy(referenceStream, contentOutputStream);
        contentOutputStream.close();

        InputStream referenceContentStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(tmpReferenceFile);

        return referenceContentStream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ...
    }
}
```

Are you detecting any possible memory leak?

Note: I know I'm returning an open `InputStream referenceContentStream`. It's closed later, beyond above code snippet.

Comment: The usual approach is the one who opened a stream should close it or instruct what to do with this stream afterwards. You mentioned that the stream is closed later, so it should be fine. Do you have any concrete issues with this code?

Comment: We're running this service inside a docker container and we're detecting some "memory leak" issues. We've tried to monitor those docker services locally, but we're not able to reproduce it... We're receivinf files from another service and when this service receive the file RAM is increased, but isn't "recovered"...